# Network status change on Windows, Linux, and how to do it in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, pyqt4

Hello friends and colleagues,

I am trying to make a function for my program on pyt4 - softphone which should determine the status of the network computer.

If the network has lost connection to the Internet the program should to wait until the network  is restored  and immediately restart the core of my app which self connects to server

Restarting the core is done by the "reload" method.

But I also would like to do cross-platform

Windows, Linux, Darwin,

I found something similar  to this link: http://www.themacaque.com/?p=751

Reload method:

```
def reload(self):
    self.config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    self.config.readfp(getConfig())
    self.tray.setIcon(self.inactiveIcon)
    self.controller.core.restart_core()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show is trying to use the native implementation because it was written not to depend on Qt4 (I'm the author of the post). If you don't have a problem in using PyQt4 in all platforms you should consider using the [networkAccessibleChanged](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#networkAccessibleChanged) signals that you can find in the [QNetworkAccessManager](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

If that is not possible you will have to write different implementations of the same interface to be used according to the platform in which you are working, for example:

- Windows: Use the code I posted on the blog.
- Linux: You can use the DBus signals that NEtworkManager has to notify you of the state of the connection.
- Mac OS X: SystemConfiguration framework as a similar set of signals to tell you the state of the connection.

If your software is open source and you don't care/mind that canonical has the copyright of the code you can take a look at the implementations we wrote for Ubuntu One [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntuone-control-tower/ubuntu-sso-client/trunk/files/head:/ubuntu_sso/networkstate/).